# jQuery data attribute selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to show some span`s with data attribute base on select options available.

I am using the below code

```
  $("#pa_varsta option").each(function(i){
        var marime =  $(this).val();
        $('.tawcvs-swatches [data-value=' + marime + ']').show();
    });
```

But i get the error

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .tawcvs-swatches [data-value=]
```

I am using Wordpress.

Any ideea, maybe regarding the jquery version?

Comment: Use `$('.tawcvs-swatches [data-value="'+marime+'"]').show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`.val()` is only for input elements not for an `<option>` element. Use `.text()` instead.</strike>

```
$("#pa_varsta option").each(function(i){
  var marime =  $(this).val();
  $('.tawcvs-swatches [data-value="' + marime + '"]').show();
});
```

It is safer to surround the attribute's value with a quote. Because sometimes, it will break the selector.